# View the first post differently, and the others all the same OCTOBERCMS (Rainlab Blog)

Tags: octobercms

I need help with this problem, I want to view the first article in one section and the others in another. This solution of mine does not work.

I think it would require some condition.

Something like, show me the latest post here, and here the others ....

My component

```
      {% set posts = __SELF__.posts %}       
        <section id="uvodniblog" class="divider">
    <div class="bt_feature_wrapper"> 
<!-- only one latest post -->
   {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="bt-feature-content bt_feature_main">
                        {% for image in post.featured_images|slice(0, 1) %} <div class="bt_item_img" style="background-image: url('{{ image.path }}');"></div> {% endfor %}
                        <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="bt_item_link" tabindex="-1"></a>
                        
                        <div class="slide_text_box">                    
                            <div class="meta-info-bg-color" style="color:w">
                                <a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="color:white;">..</a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>
                                <a href="{{ post.url }}" tabindex="-1">{{ post.title }}</a>
                            </h3>                                                                  
                             <div class="meta-info">                            
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="post-date">..</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> {% endfor %} 
    
<!-- other post -->   
  {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="bt-feature-content bt-feature-small">
                        {% for image in post.featured_images|slice(0, 1) %} <div class="bt_item_img" style="background-image: url('{{ image.path }}');"></div>{% endfor %}
                        <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="bt_item_link" tabindex="-1"></a>
                        
                        <div class="slide_text_box">                    
                            <div class="meta-info-bg-color">
                                <a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="color:white;">..</a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>
                                <a href="{{ post.url }}" tabindex="-1">{{ post.title }}</a>
                            </h3> 
    
                            <div class="meta-info">                            
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="post-date">..</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>                                                                 
                        </div>                     
                    </div>  {% endfor %} 
                    </div>
                    </div></section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```html
    {% set posts = __SELF__.posts %}       
    <section id="uvodniblog" class="divider">
        <div class="bt_feature_wrapper"> 
            <!-- only one latest post -->
            {% set latest = posts.last %}
            <div class="bt-feature-content bt_feature_main">
                {% for image in latest.featured_images|slice(0, 1) %} 
                    <div class="bt_item_img" style="background-image: url('{{ image.path }}');"></div>
                {% endfor %}
                <a href="{{ latest.url }}" class="bt_item_link" tabindex="-1"></a>
                
                <div class="slide_text_box">                    
                    <div class="meta-info-bg-color" style="color:w">
                        <a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="color:white;">..</a>
                    </div>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="{{ latest.url }}" tabindex="-1">{{ latest.title }}</a>
                    </h3>                                                                  
                     <div class="meta-info">                            
                        <ul>
                            <li class="post-date">..</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <!-- other post -->   
            {% for post in posts %}
                {% if post.id != latest.id %}
                    <div class="bt-feature-content bt-feature-small">
                        {% for image in post.featured_images|slice(0, 1) %}
                            <div class="bt_item_img" style="background-image: url('{{ image.path }}');"></div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <a href="{{ post.url }}" class="bt_item_link" tabindex="-1"></a>
                        
                        <div class="slide_text_box">                    
                            <div class="meta-info-bg-color">
                                <a href="#" tabindex="-1" style="color:white;">..</a>
                            </div>
                            <h3>
                                <a href="{{ post.url }}" tabindex="-1">{{ post.title }}</a>
                            </h3> 
    
                            <div class="meta-info">                            
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="post-date">..</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>                                                                 
                        </div>                     
                    </div> 
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %} 
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a condition based on a variable like below.

```
{% set posts = __SELF__.posts %}    
{% set latestPostId = 0 %}

{# this part will render first post #}
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if latestPostId == 0 %}
     {% set latestPostId = post.id  %}
     {# HERE you can use markup for first posts #}
  {% endif%}
{% endfor %}

{# this part will render all other post #}
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if latestPostId != post.id %}
     {# HERE you can use markup for other posts #}
  {% endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

if any doubt please comment

Comment: I guess I succeeded with the code. Just .. is it possible to disable the introductory one in other posts?

Comment: I am not sure I do not understand your requirement can you share more details

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through all posts for the first section, you should be able to get the last post directly with:

```
{% set lastPost = posts.last %}
```

and for the loop, you can skip this post with:

```
{% for post in posts if post.id != lastPost.id %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First post:

```
{% set post = posts|first (or posts.first)
```

Remaining Posts:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if loop.index != 1 %}
        ...
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```